# how to add old builds which are rejected for testflight

Tags: ios, objective-c, testflight

I have an app which is rejected for multiple times stating Apple can't check the app as the app is not loading beyond Splash screen.

[image]

When I check it at my end, its working fine with no issues.

So now what I have decided is to check through the TestFlight. For that I upload new version of app with build as 1.5.4.5 and its working fine.

***Now I am looking for a way to add 1.5.4.4 for testflight, however I can't.***

*Can someone point me in right direction on how can I add those old builds for testflight? I want to check those builds at my end on multiple devices.*

Comment: There is not enough information to understand what could have happened. 
Did you test on real devices? 

Did you try provisioning your devices with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile?
Did you try on which devices? Did you use iOS9 functionality while setting minimum deployment version to e.g. iOS7 ?

Comment: @MicheleGiuseppeFadda : I don't want to find the reason for rejection.. for now I want to know how can I put 1.5.4.4 for internal testing on testflight...

Comment: @MicheleGiuseppeFadda : is there any way where I can put old builds for internal testing in testflight? as external will need approval from Apple, I don't want to proceed that way...

Comment: You can never use a decreasing number for versions. I would use a new version, with an increased number, but generated with the sourcecode of the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use an old version as the build number must increase, you can checkout old code and make a new build from it then upload that.